# sql select min or max based on condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hi all I'm trying to find a way to select min or max from a range of data based on these conditions:

- If setuptime and processtime cols are all 0 select MIN(oprNum)
  (operation hasn't started yet so get first oprnum)
- If setuptime and process time are not 0, get max oprnum (active operation).

Based on either of these I want ONE row... Please see attached example of data. Thanks! This is part of a much larger query so i need 1 output row per prodid...

```
+------------+--------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
| ProdId     | OprNum | Company | SetupTime          | ProcessTime        |
+------------+--------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 12M0003381 | 10     | 12      | 1.3400000000000000 | 1.6100000000000000 |
+------------+--------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 12M0003381 | 10     | 12      | 0.0000000000000000 | 0.0000000000000000 |
+------------+--------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 12M0003381 | 15     | 12      | 1.0000000000000000 | 0.0000000000000000 |
+------------+--------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 12M0003381 | 50     | 12      | 0.0000000000000000 | 0.0000000000000000 |
+------------+--------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 12M0003381 | 60     | 12      | 0.0000000000000000 | 0.0000000000000000 |
+------------+--------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 12M0003381 | 60     | 12      | 0.0000000000000000 | 0.0000000000000000 |
+------------+--------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 12M0003381 | 70     | 12      | 0.0700000000000000 | 0.0400000000000000 |
+------------+--------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
| 12M0003381 | 70     | 12      | 0.0000000000000000 | 0.0000000000000000 |
+------------+--------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Have you considered to use CASE statement ?

Comment: i tried a case statement but can't seem to get the right output (1 row)

Comment: Post what you tried please :D

Comment: you could try analytic function OVER https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**updated query:** based on last comment

> if the max record has 0 times, i want to select the last record that
>   has a setuptime or process time. If I add this row to your fiddle
>   ('12M0003381',80,12,0.00,0.00) I get this row when i want the last one
>   with a setuptime or process time

logic used by this query is to simply calculate an additional column `weighted_value`. In outer query we use min over value and max over weighted value like before.

```
select 
  t.prodId,
  case when MAX(t.setuptime+ t.processtime)>0 then MAX(t.weighted_value) else MIN(t._value) end as value
from (
    select 
         prodID,
         oprnum as _value,
         setuptime,
         processtime,
         case 
           when setuptime+processtime>0 
           then oprnum 
           else NULL 
           end as weighted_value from tbl
    ) t
group by t.prodID
```

updated fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b7ecb/20

> please try this query
>
> ```
> select t1.ProdId, case when exists(
> select 1 from tbl  t2 where t2.setuptime >0 or t2.Processtime>0 and t2.prodId=t1.prodId
> )  then MAX(t1.oprNum) ELSE MIN(t1.oprNum) END
> from tbl t1
> group by ProdId
> ```
>
> sql fiddle link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c52e22/1

Comment: this does the same as the other one, however what i said in my last comment if the max record has 0 times, i want to select the last record that has a setuptime or process time.  If I add this row to your fiddle ('12M0003381',80,12,0.00,0.00) I get this row when i want the last one with a setuptime or process time, thanks for your help.

Comment: I just noticed the where clause at bottom is going to filter out any records that have all 0 processtime and 0 setuptime maybe should be... where t1.setuptime >= 0 OR t1.processtime >= 0?

Comment: yes that's what i did.  I updated your fiddle, changed all times to 0 and then i get 0 rows returned, where in this situation I want the MIN(oprnum)... which would be 10...

Comment: thanks so much for your help on this.... it's not that straightforward... can you explain to me the ELSE NULL? why not ELSE 0 or something?  How does this affect the results...

Comment: I used `NULL` as all Aggregation functions like `MAX` and `MIN` ignore `NULL` values and we did not want to consider these values. Basically here weighted value is either original value or not. MAX and MIN in this scenario will remain unaffected by 0 value. But lets say we had to work on ranges which included negative values as well, we'd be safer with `NULL`

Comment: based on all the examples i can find this looks great, thanks so much.  I'll mark as answered for now... can i ping you an email if i have any issues? thanks.  J

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85292/discussion-between-dhruvjoshi-and-jhowe).

Answer (score 3):

One way:

```
SELECT 
    ProdId, 
    CASE WHEN SUM(SetupTime) + SUM(ProcessTime) = 0 THEN MIN(oprNum) ELSE MAX(oprNum) END 
FROM T
GROUP BY ProdId
```

Comment: I think this is what i was after! can't believe i've been so stupid not to think of this... i've been going round the houses trying to come up with a solution...

Comment: how could i expand this to show MAX(OprNum) that has a time? so at the max part ideally i'd want to add MAX(oprNum) WHERE setuptime + processtime <> 0...