# sql select min or max based on condition part 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

This post is in continuatation of a problem of another post [sql select min or max based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31815050/sql-select-min-or-max-based-on-condition/31816877#31816877)

I'm trying to get a row based on various conditions.

**Scenario 1 -** get highest row if no hours exist against it that has (`setup` + `processtime` > 0).

**Scenario 2 -** if there's hours (like in this example) show next operation(`oprnum`) after this number.  (which would be 60 in `prodroute`).

The query needs to work within a CTE as it's part of a bigger query.

```
    CREATE TABLE ProdRoute
    ([ProdId] varchar(10), [OprNum] int, [SetupTime] int, [ProcessTime] numeric)
;

INSERT INTO ProdRoute
    ([ProdId], [OprNum], [SetupTime], [ProcessTime])
VALUES
    ('12M0004893', 12, 0.7700000000000000, 1.2500000000000000),
    ('12M0004893', 12, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000),
    ('12M0004893', 40, 0.0800000000000000, 0.4000000000000000),
    ('12M0004893', 50, 0.0400000000000000, 2.8000000000000000),
    ('12M0004893', 50, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000),
    ('12M0004893', 60, 0.0000000000000000, 0.6100000000000000),
    ('12M0004893', 60, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000),
    ('12M0004893', 70, 0.0000000000000000, 1.2900000000000000),
    ('12M0004893', 70, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000),
    ('12M0004893', 75, 0.0000000000000000, 3.8700000000000000),
    ('12M0004893', 75, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000),
    ('12M0004893', 80, 0.0000000000000000, 0.5500000000000000),
('12M0003571', 3, 0.8900000000000000, 0.0000000000000000),
    ('12M0003571', 3, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000),
    ('12M0003571', 7, 1.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000),
    ('12M0003571', 10, 0.3000000000000000, 0.3000000000000000),
    ('12M0003571', 10, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000),
    ('12M0003571', 20, 0.0700000000000000, 0.1000000000000000),
    ('12M0003571', 20, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000),
    ('12M0003571', 30, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000),
    ('12M0003571', 40, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000),
    ('12M0003571', 50, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000),
    ('12M0003571', 60, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000),
    ('12M0003571', 60, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000),
    ('12M0003571', 70, 0.0700000000000000, 0.1500000000000000),
    ('12M0003571', 70, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000)
;

CREATE TABLE ProdRouteTran
    ([ProdID] varchar(10), [MaxOpCompleted] int, [Hours] numeric)
;

INSERT INTO ProdRouteTran
    ([ProdID], [MaxOpCompleted], [Hours])
VALUES
    ('12M0004893', 50, 1.7800000000000000),
('12M0003571', 70, 1.2660000000000000)
;
```

expected output :

```
ProdId  OprNum
12M0004893  60

ProdId  OprNum
12M0003571  70
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on new data and last comment on the answer by asker, here's the updated query and fiddle :http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/87e2f/2

> hey i found an example that doesn't work... orderID '12M0003381'...
>   i've added data to your fiddle. I would expect to see operation 70 as
>   that's the last operation with a setup or process time... thanks!

```
select prodid, ISNULL(MAX(weighted_value),MIN(oprnum)) as value from
(           
            select 
                a.prodid,
                a.oprnum,
                ISNULL(LEAD(a.oprnum,1) OVER(Partition by a.prodID  ORDER by a.oprnum asc),a.oprnum)  * 
                MAX(case 
                    when ISNULL([Hours], 0) >= (setupTime + ProcessTime) AND (SetupTime + ProcessTime ) > 0 
                    then 1
                    else NULL
                    end) as weighted_value
            from temp1 a LEFT JOIN temp4 b 
                    ON a.OprNum = b.OPRNUM
                    AND a.ProdID = b.ProdId
            group by a.prodid,a.oprnum
) t
group by prodid
```

**Explanation for below query changes:**

The only change made to query was to handle the `NULL` value for `weighted_value` using the following syntax

```
ISNULL(LEAD(a.oprnum,1) OVER(Partition by a.prodID  ORDER by a.oprnum asc),a.oprnum)
```

The problematic part was the inner query which when run without group by clause shows what happened on a boundary case like added by user.

[image]

( See fiddle for this  here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/87e2f/3 )

Without null handling, we had a `NULL` which after `group by` clause resulted in a structure like below[image]

( See fiddle for this here:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/87e2f/5 )

As you can see on grouping the LEAD value for `prodid : 12M0003381, oprnum:70` resulted as `NULL` instead of `70` (as grouping `70` and `NULL` should give `70`).

**This is justified if `LEAD` is calculated on grouped query/table , which is actually what is happening here.**

In that case,  the `LEAD` function will not return any data for the last row of partition. This is the boundary case and must be handled correctly with `ISNULL`.

I assumed that `LEAD` `oprnum` value of last row should be corrected as `oprnum` value of current row.

**Old answer below:**

> So I tried and I am posting the fiddle link
>   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e965c/1
>
> ```
> select prodid, ISNULL(MAX(weighted_value),MIN(oprnum)) as value from 
> ( 
> select 
> a.prodid, 
> a.oprnum, 
> LEAD(a.oprnum,1) OVER(Partition by a.prodID ORDER by a.oprnum asc) * 
> MAX(case 
> when ISNULL([Hours], 0) >= (setupTime + ProcessTime) AND (SetupTime + ProcessTime ) > 0 
> then 1 
> else NULL 
> end) as weighted_value 
> from ProdRoute a LEFT JOIN COMPLETED_OP b 
> ON a.OprNum = b.OPRNUM 
> AND a.ProdID = b.ProdId 
> group by a.prodid,a.oprnum 
> ) t 
> group by prodid
> ```

Answer (score 6):

This isn't the prettiest thing I have ever written but it works. I also tested it against the other fiddle with additional data.

Modified to meet new requirement.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            A.ProdID,
            MIN(A.OprNum) AS 'OprNum'
        FROM
            #ProdRoute AS A
            JOIN 
                (
                    SELECT
                        ProdID,
                        MAX(MaxOpCompleted) AS 'OprNum'
                    FROM
                        #ProdRouteTran
                    GROUP BY
                        ProdID
                ) AS B
                ON A.ProdId = B.ProdId AND A.OprNum > B.OprNum
        GROUP BY
            A.ProdID
    ) AS [HoursA]
UNION ALL
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            DISTINCT
            A.ProdID,
            B.OprNum
        FROM
            #ProdRoute AS A
            JOIN 
                (
                    SELECT
                        ProdID,
                        MAX(MaxOpCompleted) AS 'OprNum'
                    FROM
                        #ProdRouteTran
                    GROUP BY
                        ProdID
                ) AS B
                ON A.ProdId = B.ProdId AND A.OprNum = B.OprNum
                    AND B.OprNum = (SELECT MAX(OprNum) FROM #ProdRoute WHERE ProdId = A.ProdId)
    ) AS [HoursB]
UNION ALL
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ProdId,
            MIN(OprNum) AS 'OprNum'
        FROM
            #ProdRoute
        WHERE
            ProdId NOT IN 
                (SELECT ProdId FROM #ProdRouteTran)
            AND (SetupTime <> 0 OR ProcessTime <> 0)
        GROUP BY
            ProdId
    ) AS [NoHoursA]
UNION ALL
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ProdId,
            MIN(OprNum) AS 'OprNum'
        FROM
            #ProdRoute
        WHERE
            ProdId NOT IN 
                (SELECT ProdId FROM #ProdRouteTran)
        GROUP BY
            ProdId
        HAVING
            SUM(SetupTime) = 0 AND SUM(ProcessTime) = 0
    ) AS [NoHoursB]
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm not really sure I understand your question, but here is my attempt:

```
SELECT
    pr.ProdId,
    CASE 
        WHEN SUM(SetupTime) + SUM(ProcessTime) > 0 THEN MAX(x.OprNum)
        ELSE MAX(pr.OprNum)
    END
FROM ProdRoute pr
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ProdID, MAX(MaxOpCompleted) AS OprNum
    FROM ProdRouteTran
    GROUP BY ProdID
)prt
    ON prt.ProdId = pr.ProdID
    AND prt.OprNum = pr.OprNum
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 OprNum FROM ProdRoute 
    WHERE 
        ProdId = pr.ProdId
        AND OprNum > pr.OprNum
    ORDER BY OprNum
)x
GROUP BY pr.ProdId
ORDER BY pr.ProdId
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this -

```
-- display the next operation, if condition match
SELECT do_exists.ProdId, do_exists.OprNum
FROM ProdRoute pr
INNER JOIN ProdRouteTran prt 
    ON prt.ProdId = pr.ProdId 
    AND pr.OprNum = prt.MaxOpCompleted 
    AND (pr.SetupTime + pr.ProcessTime) > 0
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP(1) pr.* 
    FROM ProdRoute pr
    WHERE prt.ProdID = pr.ProdId
    AND   pr.OprNum > prt.MaxOpCompleted
    ORDER BY pr.OprNum
) do_exists


UNION ALL

-- display the max operation, if matching data is not found in ProdRoute. 
---- Matching Data not found - 1) There is entry in ProdRoute for particular ProdId but hours is not present
----                           2) There is no entry in ProdRoute for a particular ProdId    
SELECT pr.ProdId, MAX(pr.OprNum) OprNum
FROM ProdRoute pr
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT pr.ProdId
    FROM ProdRoute pr
    INNER JOIN ProdRouteTran prt 
        ON prt.ProdId = pr.ProdId 
        AND pr.OprNum = prt.MaxOpCompleted 
        AND (pr.SetupTime + pr.ProcessTime) > 0
) pr_ex ON pr_ex.ProdId = pr.ProdId
WHERE pr_ex.ProdId IS NULL 
GROUP BY pr.ProdId
```

Answer (score 6):

I get the correct result with this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6066e/1/0).

However I am not sure I fully understand the `nothing >0` case. A little more data with all the cases could be usefull.

```
; With data as (
    Select r.ProdId
    , opr = case when h > 0 then  isnull(min(p.OprNum), r.OprNum) else  max(p.OprNum) end
    From (
        Select pr.ProdId, pr.OprNum, h = max(pr.SetupTime + pr.ProcessTime)     
        From ProdRoute as pr
        Inner Join ProdRouteTran as prt on pr.ProdId = prt.ProdID and pr.OprNum = prt.MaxOpCompleted
        Group By pr.ProdId, pr.OprNum
    ) as r
    left join ProdRoute as p on p.ProdId = r.ProdId and p.OprNum > r.OprNum
    Group By r.ProdId, r.OprNum, r.h
)
Select * From data
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not entirely sure if I understood what you are trying to do, but could it be that this is the equivalent?

```
SELECT
   t.ProdId,
   CASE WHEN r.OprNum IS NULL THEN t.MaxOpCompleted ELSE r.OprNum END AS OprNum
FROM
   ProdRouteTran t
   LEFT JOIN
      ProdRoute r
   ON
      r.ProdId = t.ProdId AND r.SetupTime + r.ProcessTime > 0 AND
      r.OprNum > t.MaxOpCompleted AND NOT EXISTS(
         SELECT * FROM ProdRoute p WHERE p.ProdId = t.ProdId AND
            p.OprNum > t.MaxOpCompleted AND p.OprNum < r.OprNum)
```